# What's the best way to lay out a React/webpack project with an API backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm a little late to the party, but I'm just getting started with React. I have a base project that I'm serving with webpack-dev-server, but now I need to actually get data for it.

My chosen API is [Strava](http://strava.com/developers). I'm trying to use [the recommended API wrapper for node](https://github.com/unboundev/node-strava-v3), but I've come to a point where I don't want to expose my API keys and know that I need to create my own API endpoints. I was about to start creating an Express server to quickly create these endpoints, but I feel like there might be something that I'm missing.

- Is there a better way to go about this with webpack/webpack-dev-server?
- If I want this working on the internet, I know that I'll need at least one node instance running to serve my API endpoints; I just want to make sure there's not some super-simple, possibly webpack-based (to keep everything in the same family) solution that I could then, later, just deploy on a ready-made node server.

My assumption is that I'll just be better off creating two projects:

1. Static content (currently webpacked and served with webpack-dev-server for development)
2. Express server for API-wrapping.

If that's the case, is there a simple way to point hook Express up with my static project (everything webpack does is sent out to an /app/dist directory) for production deployment?

Comment: Which solution did you opt for? I'm facing the same dilemma. :)

Comment: @mosu work took over and I haven't gotten a chance to do anything with this proj :(

Comment: I'm not sure if this solves your problem (I think it does solve my) but you can try this: start two servers on two different ports. One is handling all routes and the other one specific routes like the API routes. Check out the code in the response. This window is limited in characters.

Comment: Ignore the other comment. Here's what I did: I tried this and looks like is working: app.get('/myAPI', function(req, res) {
  res.json({ // this returns data for the API
  });
})

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html')); // This returns the react main html. 
});